# Quiero ejecutar un comando cmd en lenguaje C y guardar en un fichero el mensaje de ejecucion del programa

Tags: c

Quiero ejecutar un comando cmd  en lenguaje C y guardar en un fichero el mensaje de ejecucion del programa.

mi programa:

//Funcion apagar la musica.

```
if(lista->musica==1) // Si musicca == 1; cerrar la musica
{
    printf("\n\n   Cerrando musica.mp3 \n");
    system("taskkill /IM wmplayer.exe");
    Sleep(500);      // Es necesario hacer tiempo para que el programa cierre el wplayer antes de 
                     //pasar a la siguiente instruccion y evitar crasheos;
    system("cls");
}
```

Cuando se ejecuta el programa, me imprime por pantalla:

Cerrando musica.mp3
CORRECTO: señal de terminación enviada al proceso "wmplayer.exe" con PID 12580.

Y me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de guardar ese mensaje en una cadena de caracteres (no creo que se pueda) o lo que tenia pensado, guardarlo de alguna forma en un fichero, para por ejemplo escanear el fichero posteriormente y guardar el PID en una valiable de tipo int.

Si alguien sabe como hacerlo le agradecería que me respondiese porque me tiene comida la cabeza este asunto. Gracias.

Comment: Si quieres hacerlo en tu programa, tendras que usar `_popen` para hacer un pipe en el que puedas leer el `stdout` del comando. Luego a un buffer, y luego a tu archivo. O si prefieres no complicarte con la programacion puedes hacer `comando > archivo` dentro de `system`.

Comment: si quieres guardar varios registros tambien puedes añadir al comando en vez de `comando > archivo` `comando >> archivo` así te lo añadirá al final del archivo en vez de borrar lo que había antes.

Comment: Vale ya se como decís, estudie una vez comandos en linux y era muy parecido tendré que volverme a mirar esos comandos para refrescar un poco y adaptarlo a c y a cmd, gracias por la ayuda.